# Scala initialize set from another set

Tags: scala, set

It is not clear how to create a new Set from an existing one.

```
scala> val s = Set(1,2,3)
```

Try adding s directly in constructor:

```
scala> val v = Set(s)
v: scala.collection.mutable.Set[scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]] = Set(Set(1, 2, 3))
```

Um that's a *nested* set..

So let us try to take each element :

```
val v = Set[Int](s:_*)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]
 required: Seq[Int]
       val v = Set[Int](s:_*)
```

How about a list?

```
val v = Set(  s.toList)
v: scala.collection.mutable.Set[List[Int]] = Set(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got there:

```
scala> val v = Set(s.toSeq: _*)
v: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

You've probably already tried `toSet` and discovered you just get back the same `Set`, but another option is to use [`to[Col[_]]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set), passing `Set` as the `Col[_]` which *does* give you a new set:

```
scala> val s = Set(1, 2, 3)
scala> System.identityHashCode(s)
  res0: Int = 908978764

scala> val v = s.toSet
scala> System.identityHashCode(v)
  res1: Int = 908978764              // No good - same object 

scala> val w = s.to[Set]
scala> System.identityHashCode(w)
  res2: Int = 1069495836             // New object
```

Is it more efficient than @dk14's approach? I don't know. But it's possibly a little bit more obvious to the casual reader.

Comment: yours should be faster

Answer (score 2):

A generic approach to copying (duplicating) a [Traversable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Traversable), simply by iterating over each item,

```
val v = s.map(identity)
```